# CreateGraphicsPipelineState fails with E_INVALIDARG

Tags: c++, directx-12

Creation of Pipeline State Object in Directx 12 fails with `E_INVALIDARG` and debug layer outputs a bunch of nonsense saying data in `D3D12_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_STATE_DESC` instance is invalid:

> D3D12 ERROR: ID3D12Device::CreateBlendState: DestBlendAlpha[ 0 ] is
>   trying to use a D3D11_BLEND value (0x4) that manipulates color, which
>   is invalid. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #115:
>   CREATEBLENDSTATE_INVALIDDESTBLENDALPHA] D3D12 ERROR:
>   ID3D12Device::CreateDepthStencilState: BackFace.StencilFailOp has an
>   unrecognized value. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #106:
>   CREATEDEPTHSTENCILSTATE_INVALIDBACKFACESTENCILFAILOP] D3D12 ERROR:
>   ID3D12Device::CreateDepthStencilState: BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp has
>   an unrecognized value. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #107:
>   CREATEDEPTHSTENCILSTATE_INVALIDBACKFACESTENCILZFAILOP] D3D12 ERROR:
>   ID3D12Device::CreateDepthStencilState: BackFace.StencilPassOp has an
>   unrecognized value. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #108:
>   CREATEDEPTHSTENCILSTATE_INVALIDBACKFACESTENCILPASSOP] D3D12 ERROR:
>   ID3D12Device::CreateDepthStencilState: BackFace.StencilFunc has an
>   unrecognized value. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #109:
>   CREATEDEPTHSTENCILSTATE_INVALIDBACKFACESTENCILFUNC] D3D12 ERROR:
>   ID3D12Device::CreateRasterizerState: FillMode has an unrecognized
>   value. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #95:
>   CREATERASTERIZERSTATE_INVALIDFILLMODE] D3D12 ERROR:
>   ID3D12Device::CreateRasterizerState: FillMode must be
>   D3D12_FILL_MODE_SOLID when ConservativeRaster is
>   D3D12_CONSERVATIVE_RASTERIZATION_MODE_ON: FillMode =
>   D3D12_FILL_MODE_WIREFRAME, ConservativeRaster =
>   D3D12_CONSERVATIVE_RASTERIZATION_MODE_ON. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #95:
>   CREATERASTERIZERSTATE_INVALIDFILLMODE] D3D12 ERROR:
>   ID3D12Device::Create*: The specified node mask (0xcccccccc) contains a
>   bit set beyond the node count of the device. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #900: INVALID_NODE_INDEX]

list goes on...

Looks like the memory is corrupted when it's not, I've checked all the values over and over, they're fine. 
At least *some* of the values must be correct, look at the last message for example, it says

> The specified node mask (0xcccccccc)

… I'm sure it's not 0xcccccccc before `CreateGraphicsPipelineState` call, debugger confirms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that exe built on my machine would fail to create PSO on other computers, but if the project was to be built on other machine and run on mine, there would be no PSO problems.

Reinstalling Windows SDK helped eliminate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've read answers from people claiming that reinstalling or changing the SDK version solved the issue for them. But not for me. It was actually the `dxil.dll` that was missing next to the `.exe` of my program.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to zero-initialize your `psoDesc` first, to avoid incorrect values like `0xcccccccc` in the `NodeMask` field:

```
D3D12_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_STATE_DESC psoDesc = {};
```